# Should the number of executor core for Apache Spark be set to 1 in YARN mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-2.0

My question: Is it true that running Apache Spark applications in YARN master, with deploy-mode as either client or cluster, the executor-cores should always be set to 1?

I am running an application processing millions of data on a cluster with `200 data nodes` each having `14 cores`. It runs perfect when I use `2 executor-cores` and `150 executors` on YARN, but one of the cluster admins is asking me to use 1 executor-core. He is adamant that Spark in YARN should be used with 1 executor core, because otherwise it will be stealing resources from other users. He points me to this page on Apache docs where it says the default value for executor-core is 1 for YARN.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

So, is it true we should use only 1 for executor-cores?

If the executors use 1 core, aren't they single threaded?

Kind regards,

Comment: It recommends less core per executor and more total executor. So that the parallelism would be better. Ex; 100nodes; each has 8cores and 16gb ram. Recommended configuration is that 1core, 2gbram, 700executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we run spark application using a cluster manager like Yarn, there’ll be several daemons that’ll run in the background like NameNode, Secondary NameNode, DataNode, JobTracker and TaskTracker. So, while specifying num-executors, we need to make sure that we leave aside enough cores (~1 core per node) for these daemons to run smoothly.

ApplicationMaster is responsible for negotiating resources from the ResourceManager and working with the NodeManagers to execute and monitor the containers and their resource consumption. If we are running spark on yarn, then we need to budget in the resources that AM would need

```
Example 
**Cluster Config:**
200 Nodes
14 cores per Node
```

Leave 1 core per node for Hadoop/Yarn daemons => Num cores available per node = 14-1 = 13
So, Total available of cores in cluster = 13 x 200 = 2600

Let’s assign 5 core per executors => **--executor-cores** = 5 (for good HDFS throughput)

Number of available executors = (total cores/num-cores-per-executor) = 2600/5 = 520

Leaving 1 executor for ApplicationManager => **--num-executors** = 519

> Please note : This is just a sample recommended configuration , you
>   may wish to revise based upon the performance of your application.
>
> Also A better practice is to monitor the node resources while you
>   execute your job , this gives a better picture of the resource
>   utilisation in your cluster

Comment: Thanks Neha. This is exactly what I was aware of. You've taken 5 cores per executor in your hypothetical example above where I used just 2 in my case (and spread across 200 executors) and found the performance was acceptable. The comment from Admin that I should ALWAYS use 1 core per executor for YARN is what I need clarification on. He says it is what Apache Spark docs says. It doesn't make any sense does it?

Comment: The documentation clears says "Most of the properties that control internal settings have reasonable default values." These are defaults and not the mandatory ones. In yarn master mode the default is 1, therefore each executor will use only 1 core by default. However , if you more cores , there is absolutely no harm in using more cores as long as you leave behind atleast 1 core for the hadoop daemon

Comment: for my usecases i generally see that 1 executor core performs the best, though you see many blog posts suggesting 4 or 5 cores per executor as optimum

Comment: onemore thing u have to keep in mind is, say u have executor which is digesting single task --and this can happen for various reasons data-locality, etc. in this case ur executor will be given 2 cores, but probably only 1 core is in use.